# $σ(f(T))$ not equal to $f(σ(T))?$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I have no idea how to work it out and couldn't find any clue. Sorry if it's too trivial.

Let *T* be a bounded and non-normal operator, *f(z)=zz'* defined complex space (z' is a complex conjugate here).

What can be an example of such a *T*, that spectrum *σ(f(T))* is not equal to *f(σ(T))*? As far as I checked, any simple finite matrix operator doesn't work here. Maybe some exponential?

Edit: corrected descriptions.

Comment: What is $\sigma?$ What is $f?$

Comment: maybe $f$ is not linear...

Comment: I've already editted the post, sorry for unclear descriptions. σ is an operators spectrum and the f(z) is now corrected

Comment: What is $f(T)$?

Comment: I'm familiar with this idea for analytic $f$, but in this case, I'm not sure how to define $f$ acting on operators. For example, $g(z) = z'z$ is equal to $f$ because of commutativity of scalars, but how do each of these generalize to operators (let's say matrices for simplicity) and do they mean the same thing? In what context is this arising? Is it from a textbook, a paper, your own work, etc.?

Comment: I'm trying to solve some set of problems I got from a friend (not as an assignment, just to learn). For operators, this function is TT', so basically the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the shift operator acting on $\ell^2\mathbb{N})$ by $Se_{n+1}=e_n$ and $Se_1=0.$ Then $SS^*= I$ and $\sigma(S)=\{|z|\le 1\}.$ Thus $\sigma(f(S))=\{1\}$ and $f(\sigma(S))=[0,1].$

Comment: What is $e_n$ and do we have $SS^*=S^*S$?

Comment: @Diger No. The operator is not normal. For normal operators the phenomenon cannot occur. $e_n$ denote the elements of standard basis.

Comment: Ok, I see. And how do you figure the spectrum of $S$, $|z|\leq 1$?

Comment: @Diger  For $|z|<1$ we have $Su_z=zu_z$ where $u_z=\{z^n\}.$ Hence the open unit disc consists of the eigenvalues of $S.$

Comment: I assume in your notation $e_n=z^n$, is that correct? Woudn't then $Su_z=zu_z$ be equivalent to $Se_n=e_{n+1}$? What happens if $|z|\geq 1$?

Comment: No, the symbol $e_n$ denotes the sequence whose all terms are $0$ except for the $i$th term which is equal $1.$ Thus $\{z^n\} =\sum z^ n e_n.$ This sequence is square summable iff |z|<1.$

Comment: Hm, I'm confused, before you said $e_n$ denotes the standard basis, by which I understand for example a vector $e_n=(0,...,0,1,0,....0)^t$.

Comment: Exactly, that's the standard basis, and that what I meant in my comments.  I can only repeat that $\{z^n\} =\sum z^ne_n.$

Comment: Ok, I think I missunderstood. What would happen if I discard squaresummability? I mean, $u_z$ would still be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $z$, but $|z|>1$. Where would that lead to an issue?